# Tournure "que de"

Tags: grammaire, stylistique

Dans *Rythmes pittoresques* de Marie Krysinska :

> Et tandis que la vitre miroite comme de l'eau dormant, **que de** charme inquiétant et **que de** confidences muettes, entre les plis des rideaux blancs, rouges ou roses.

> Mais comme ils pleurent les lamentables rideaux de mousseline fanée, / **Que de** plaintes et **que d**'angoisses dans le lambeau de percale salie qui semble pris à un linceul ;

Est-ce commun ou correct d'utiliser **que de** comme dans les cas ci-dessus ? C'est la première fois que je vois cette tournure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans ces phrases *que de* sert à exprimer des exclamations.

*Que de* est un outil exclamatif dont l'emploi, quoique littéraire, me semble relativement courant. Il sert à exprimer l'exclamation sur une (grande) quantité, *que* est ici un adverbe exclamatif, et il est suivi de *de* qui est l'article partitif devant le groupe nominal.

> Que d'eau, que d'eau ! ([Citation](https://www.histoire-en-citations.fr/citations/mac-mahon-que-d-eau-que-d-eau) du président Mac Mahon).

- Construction devant un groupe sujet + verbe :
  Que c'est compliqué !
- Construction devant un groupe nominal : 
  Que de complications !

Il pourrait y avoir, dans l'extrait cité dans la question, un point d'exclamation en fin de phrase. Mais, peut-être parce que les groupes nominaux sont longs, son absence ne m'étonne pas. En tous les cas, si lus, chacun des membres de phrase concernés devrait adopter l'intonation de la phrase exclamative.

Comment: *Ô Liberté, que de crimes l'on commet en ton nom !*